How can I get a calendar to stop showing alerts?
I have added a calendar to my phone with the intent of having entries show up in my calendar, but so as not to receive any notifications when  they change (this is a work calendar, and it is my personal phone; I don't want to get push notifications from work events!).
However, this does not seem to be working correctly: in the calendar settings, I have "Event Alerts" set to off, but I still get notifications popping up when new events show up in this calendar.
I don't want to disable all calendar events: I have other shared calendars that I do like to see notifications for. How can I disable only the popups and alerts from this one calendar?
Note that this is iOS 18; I have seen questions such as How to disable notifications for a single calendar, in iOS6 which seem to suggest that what I have done should work but... it doesn't.

Could you explain "what I have done should work but... it doesn't.". What are you doing?

I went into the individual calendar settings and turned off "event alerts", which according to everything I have read (and common sense) should mean that there are no alerts for the calendar. However, every time a new invite appears I get a notification on my phone.
